# Select all anchor tags with an href attribute that contains one of multiple values via xpath in lxml / Python

Tags: python, xpath, operators, lxml, contains

I need to automatically scan lots of html documents for ad banners that are surrounded by an anchor tag, e.g.:

```
<a href="http://ad_network.com/abc.html">
    <img src="ad_banner.jpg">
</a>
```

As a newbie with xpath, I can select such anchors via lxml like so:

```
text = '''
    <a href="http://ad_network.com/abc.html">
        <img src="ad_banner.jpg">
    </a>'''

root = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
print root.xpath('//a[contains(@href,("ad_network.")) or contains(@href,("other_ad_network."))][descendant::img]')
```

In the example I check on two different domains: "ad_network." and "other_ad_network.". However, there are over 25 domains to check and the xpath expression would get terribly long by connecting all those conatains-directives by "or". And I fear the expression would be pretty inefficient concerning CPU ressources. Is there some syntax for checking on multiple "contains" values?

I could get the concerned links also via regex in a single line of code. Yet, although the html code is normalized by lxml, regex seems never to be a good choice for that kind of work ... Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be that bad just to do a bunch of 'or's. Build the xpath with python so that you don't get writer's cramp and then precompile it. The actual xpath code is in libxml and should be fast.

```
sites=['aaa', 'bbb']
contains = ' or '.join('contains(@href,(%s))' % site for site in sites)
anchor_xpath = etree.XPath('//a[%s][descendant::img]' % contains)
```

Comment: I like the approach ... I'm just waiting to see if there's an even shorter/more efficient solution before accepting it. Do you have a clue what's faster: using one regex on the html document or this rather long xpath?

Comment: @Nasmon - my gut feeling is that the regex would be a bit faster but I've been on projects that used a lot of xpath and they ran okay. This could all be a case of premature optimization. regex'ing the html docs is problematic - you want to stick with an xml parser - but using a regex in the xpath would be okay.