# How can I select a link in a page based on its href attribute, using Selenium?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium.

I am trying to select a link based on the "href" attribute. I can’t use an XPath expression here, because the links keep moving around the page every time the page loads.

Comment: If you are using webdriver you can use `By.linkText()`  and specify the text in your `anchor` tag.

Comment: I cant use that, the text in anchor tag is same for all the links here.:(

Comment: Jaydev, can you please explain giving an example.

Comment: <a href="http://www.abc.com/search?q=cheese">search for cheese</a>><a href="http://www.pqr.com/search?q=cheese">search for cheese</a>><a href="http://www.alldifferent.com/search?q=cheese">search for cheese</a>>

Comment: @Jaydev: If they have same text inside tag then they must be going(reffering) to same page. And also if every time the tags move arround, so it does not matter on which one you click. So you can safely use the `By.linkText()` method.

Comment: No Mr. Yadav, they dont redirect to same links. That's the basic prob in my case. When i say they keep moving around the page, I mean to say that all these links appear in a table and they interchange their places in every page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the XPath expression *//a[contains(@href,'yourhref')]* and *by.xpath* or a similar CSS selector.

When you use *//*, it means a relative XPath expression, so no matter what the hierarchy, if your *href* attribute is unique, this would do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `By.linkText` or `By.partialLinkText` e.g.

`<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=cheese">search for cheese</a>>`

`WebElement cheese = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("cheese"));`

This example has been extracted from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-link-text)

Comment: I cant use that. In my case here, text in anchor tag is same for all the links, only unique attribute is the href which is different for each link.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975960/select-all-anchor-tags-with-an-href-attribute-that-contains-one-of-multiple-valu) XPath construction method or the following method.

```
public void clickLink(WebDriver driver) {

    List<WebElement> aList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (WebElement el : aList) {

        // if (el.getAttribute("href").contains("your href partial value")

        if (el.getAttribute("href")
                .equalsIgnoreCase("your full hreff text")) {
            el.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Use the *if* condition as per your requirement. either partial or full comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS selector. Example:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href=(your href)]")
```